# Align Popup Menu to the right side in RecyclerView Item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I am using `Popup Menu` at every list item in my `RecyclerView` and whenever I click on the overflow icon (3 dots) of any item of my `RecyclerView`, the popup menu appears at the very left side of my layout.

[image]

I have tried applying the gravity using the `setGravity` method but it doesn't work at all.

But I have noted one thing that it was working fine earlier when I was actually using `ListView` and not `RecyclerView`.

MyAdapter Code Sample:

```
public class RecyclerAssetsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAssetsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<AssetsBean> assetsBeanList;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerAssetsAdapter(List<AssetsBean> assetsBeanList, Context context) {
        this.assetsBeanList = assetsBeanList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void filter(List<AssetsBean> newList){
        assetsBeanList = newList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,viewGroup,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.type.setText(assetsBeanList.get(i).getassetName());
        viewHolder.desc.setText(assetsBeanList.get(i).getassetDesc());
        viewHolder.building.setText(assetsBeanList.get(i).getCreatedAt());

        final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
        viewHolder.overflowIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, viewHolder.building);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.assets_popup_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
                popupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                popupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                popupMenu.show();
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.view: //view
                                Fragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
                                Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
                                args1.putString("objectId",assetsBeanList.get(i).getObjectId());
//                                args.putString("assetType",mb.getassetName());
                                args1.putString("qrcode",assetsBeanList.get(i).getQrcode());
                                detailsFragment.setArguments(args1);
                                ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.my_fragment,detailsFragment).commit();
                                break;
                            case R.id.edit:
                                Fragment formFragment = new FormFragment();
                                Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
                                args2.putString("objectId",assetsBeanList.get(i).getObjectId());
                                formFragment.setArguments(args2);
                                ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.my_fragment,formFragment).commit();
                                break;
                            case R.id.see_logs: //see logs
                                Fragment assetsLogFragment = new AssetLogFragment();
                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putString("objectId",assetsBeanList.get(i).getObjectId());
                                args.putString("assetType",assetsBeanList.get(i).getassetName());
                                args.putString("assetDesc",assetsBeanList.get(i).getassetDesc());
                                assetsLogFragment.setArguments(args);
                                ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.my_fragment,assetsLogFragment).commit();
                                break;
                            case R.id.move:
                                //move to new organisation
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                builder1.setTitle("Move To Department");
                                EditText editText = new EditText(context);
                                editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                builder1.setView(editText);
                                builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    }
                                });
//                                ParseQuery<ParseObject> assetQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("assets");
//                                assetQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId",mb.getObjectId());
//                                assetQuery.include("organization");
//                                assetQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
//                                    @Override
//                                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
//
//                                    }
//                                });
                                break;
                            case R.id.delete: //delete assest
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                builder.setTitle("Delete");
                                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this Asset and its associated log?");
                                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("assets");
                                        query.whereEqualTo("objectId",assetsBeanList.get(i).getObjectId());
                                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> logQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("logs");
                                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                                                for(ParseObject object: objects){
                                                    object.deleteEventually();

                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                        logQuery.whereMatchesQuery("asset",query);
                                        logQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                                                for(ParseObject object: objects){
                                                    object.deleteEventually();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                        assetsBeanList.remove(assetsBeanList.get(i));
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    }
                                });
                                builder.show();
                                break;
                            default:break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return assetsBeanList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView type,desc,building;
        ImageView overflowIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.session_name);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.session_desc);
            building = itemView.findViewById(R.id.created_at);
            overflowIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.overflow_icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you dont post whole adapter code?

Comment: Done, pasted the whole code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#PopupMenu(android.content.Context,%20android.view.View)) `PopupMenu` takes **context** and **anchor view** as its constructor parameters. I guess you want popup menu to appear near to overflow icon when it is clicked.

In your code you are passing wrong view as anchor to `PopupMenu` constructor:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, viewHolder.building);
```

Try replacing **viewHolder.building** with **viewHolder.overflowIcon**:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, viewHolder.overflowIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, viewHolder.overflowIcon);
```

popupMenu.showAsDropDown(id);//id is view id where u wan to display